# What methods allow learning "changes" in data, and then generating synthetic output?

Tags: convolution, transfer-function

Suppose I'm interested in a process of the sort:

> Original data -> Something happened to data -> Result data

More particularly, consider that we observe many results of "something happened to data":

> Original data -> Case 1 of something happened to data -> Result observation type 1 
> Original data -> Case 2 of something happened to data -> Result observation type 2 
>  ...

Then consider that we get:

> Original data 2

which is in some way similar to Original data 2, but this similarity might as well be in number ranges, in type of data (e.g. frequency data), it might be the visual form of the data (similar spectrograms) or it might be in the known source of the data (e.g. if original data was a plant image, then original data is also a plant image).

I want to figure out a function that allows me **to do to Original data 2, what we observed happening with Original data.** Sort of like convolving Original data 2 with the black box that could've been learned with Original data.

But is this just convolution? Is it convolutional neural networks? I've only seen CNNs applied to classification, not data transformation.

More particularly, is this a problem for which there exists "automatic theory", or is it more like a problem that would require "manual modelling using different components"? I.e. synthesizing the black box, rather than *learning* it?

Related:

- [Cesar A. Gomez, "Are there methods for learning the transfer function of a system?"](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Are_there_methods_for_learning_the_transfer_function_of_a_system)
- Wikipedia [Transfer Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) page.
- [Generative adversarial network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network)

But again I'm not talking about just classification, but also filters, predicting distributions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are describing here is basic system theory.

As long as "something happened to data" is LTI (linear & time invariant), than the system can be fully characterized by it's transfer function or impulse response. The output of an LTI system for any input can easily be calculated by a variety of methods, with convolution being one of them.

If the system is non-linear or time variant, things get much more complicated.

There is a ton of literature on "[system identification](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/gs/about-system-identification.html)".

Comment: I guess I'm specifically asking for the non-linear and time variant part. In another sense, I was looking for "a CNN for generating an output, rather than predicting a class for the input". So if we train a CNN or something, then can we produce a synthetic output?

Comment: Possibly related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network